# SQL Script : EXEC sp_Msforeachdb

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-administration

When I run this SQL script in SQL Server 2012, I get an error : near '?' is not correct

```
--USE AdventureWorks2012
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb '
USE [?];
drop table #DBSizes
create table #DBSizes (
               [name] nvarchar(256),
   [rows] int,
   [reserved] varchar(18),
   [data] varchar(18),
   [index_size] varchar(18),
   [unused] varchar(18)
   )
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "INSERT INTO #DBSizes EXEC sp_spaceused '?' "
'
select DB_NAME() AS DB_na,
       [name] AS Table_na,
       [rows] AS[Row_count],
   [reserved] AS[Reserved_size],
   [data] AS[Data_size],
   [index_size] AS[Index_size],
   [unused] AS[Unused_size],
   CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()) AS [Date_sql]
   --CONVERT (time(7), SYSDATETIME()) AS [Time_sql]
from #DBSizes
```

I run these SQL script,it's okay ,but it only use one db:AdventureWorks2012

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
--EXEC sp_Msforeachdb '
--USE [?];
drop table #DBSizes
create table #DBSizes (
               [name] nvarchar(256),
   [rows] int,
   [reserved] varchar(18),
   [data] varchar(18),
   [index_size] varchar(18),
   [unused] varchar(18)
   )
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "INSERT INTO #DBSizes EXEC sp_spaceused '?' "
--'
select DB_NAME() AS DB_na,
       [name] AS Table_na,
       [rows] AS[Row_count],
   [reserved] AS[Reserved_size],
   [data] AS[Data_size],
   [index_size] AS[Index_size],
   [unused] AS[Unused_size],
   CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()) AS [Date_sql]
   --CONVERT (time(7), SYSDATETIME()) AS [Time_sql]
from #DBSizes
```

I want to get all db information, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm limited on time to try and replicate this, but I'm assuming you need to escape your single quotes, on the line where you have:

`EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "INSERT INTO #DBSizes EXEC sp_spaceused '?' "`

shouldn't you have:

`EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "INSERT INTO #DBSizes EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'' "`

Comment: What is the new problem?